# one query in tree conditions

Tags: java, oracle

I have one table in database that contains 3 foreign keys to another tables(this three tables name are: manager,worker and employee). in  each row only one foreign key is filled.I need to write one query that with attention which column of fk is filled in where clause specified condition is performed.
I write simple query in jpa but doesn't work properly

```
 select b 
 from allEmployees b 
 where b.manager.name= :name 
    OR b.worker.name = :name 
   OR b.employee.name= :name
```

do you have any idea?I have to resolve it but i don't have any idea

Comment: Could you clarify what you want the output to be? I.e. do you want a column which indicates which of the tables this record is associated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could use nested decodes for this e.g. if the column names were a, b and c the query would be;

```
select decode(a,null,decode(b,null,decode(c,null,'None','Key3'),'Key2'),'Key1') as result from table
```

for example if your table looked like this:

```
A | B | C
----------
x |   |
  | x |
  |   | x
  |   |
```

Then the query would return: Key1, Key2, Key3, None for those 4 rows.

Comment: thanks dear chris.can you help me how write my query to your format

Comment: what is 'none' ,'key1','key2' , 'key3' ?

Comment: Hi, 'none','key1','key2'&'key3' are just the labels I have given. The syntax of decode is decode( expression , search , result [, search , result]... [, default] ) see http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php for more details. If you let me know the name of the table, columns and the text you want returned if it is col a, b or c I can update the example.

Comment: select * from allEmployee where if b.manager is not null then b.manager.name =:name elseif b.employee is not null then b.employee.name =:name elseif b.worker is not null then b.worker.name=:name

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused by your syntax above, what is b.manager.name for example? It sounds like what you want may be outer joins rather than the decode I suggested above.

Comment: in three table manager,employee and worker I have the same column that named it "name".b.manager.name is jpql format and says in table allEmployee I have a column with  manager name that refrence to table manager(manager column is foreign key) and manager table i have column name

Answer (score 0):

your original query must be work fine, maybe something in data can be the problem. Assuming that table columns are String, you can try:

```
select b 
  from allEmployees b 
  where upper(b.manager.name) = upper(:name) 
  OR upper(b.worker.name) = upper(:name) 
  OR upper(b.employee.name) = upper(:name)
```

Another way is using set operations:

```
select b 
  from allEmployees b 
  where upper(b.manager.name) = upper(:name) 
UNION
select b 
  from allEmployees b 
  where upper(b.worker.name) = upper(:name) 
UNION
select b 
  from allEmployees b 
  where upper(b.employee.name) = upper(:name)
```

By the other hand, this can be a design error, think what happen if the name for manager and employee are the same, also you have to review normalization, is better to have ID´s for primary keys instead names.

HTH

Comment: thanks your answer.my query is example of my problem.i don't set varchar value.my problem is i have 3 condition that each row in db occoured one case

Comment: i need select all any rows that one of this sitution occoured it